Trying to set Azure Activity Log from Tenant Root(all subscriptions) getting Resource Provider Error
I'm trying to send the activity logs from all subscriptions in my lab to Sentinel.
I'm Global Administrator and even gave myself 'User Access Administrator'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin?tabs=azure-portal#Overview
I'm following the steps in the Sentinel Lab -
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel/blob/master/Solutions/Training/Azure-Sentinel-Training-Lab/Modules/Module-2-Data-Connectors.md
I've added them in Content Hub and when trying to go through the 'Data Connector' steps the 'Launch Azure Policy Assignment wizard'  and I set it to 'Tenant Root Group'.
I point it to the LA workspace but when I click on Create I get the following error -
"RP Registration failed
Failed to register Microsoft.PolicyInsights resource provider with assignment scope.  The client(me Global Admin) with object id 'me' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.PolicyInsights/register/action' over scope '/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroup ..."
I've checked and Microsoft.PolicyInsights is registered in all the subscriptions.
If I add one subscription BUT under 'Remediation' do a 'select the Remediation tab and mark the Create a remediation task check box.' will it add all my current subscriptions or just new ones?
Is there anything else I can try?  I was more curious how admin handle multiple subscriptions and activity logs.
Thank you!!

Note that, User Administrator works only to assign RBAC roles under management groups and cannot perform any other operation.
Similarly, Global Administrator can have complete access on tenant/directory but cannot perform any action under subscription or management group level.
To resolve the error, you need to either assign Owner or Contributor roles to the user under management group like this:

If you prefer least privileged role, you can assign Resource Policy Contributor role to the user under management group that contains "Microsoft.PolicyInsights/register/action" permission.
Reference:
Can User Access Administrator assign Azure policies? - Microsoft Q&A by Stanislav Zhelyazkov
